# Anbox - Segmentation fault (core image recorded) / Segmentation fault (core image dumped)

Tags: anbox

### ANBOX SESSION-MANAGER LOG IN ENGLISH TRANSLATED FROM PORTUGUESE:

```
caua@caua-HP-Stream-Laptop-11-y0XX:~$ anbox session-manager
[ 2021-12-13 17:33:09] [Renderer.cpp:128@initialize] Failed to select EGL configuration
Stack trace (most recent call last) in thread 2582:
#7    Object "[0xffffffffffffffff]", at 0xffffffffffffffff, in 
#6    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0x7f2f519c5292, in clone
#5    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", at 0x7f2f51d36608, in 
#4    Object "/snap/anbox/213/usr/bin/anbox", at 0x56411d01b314, in emugl::Thread::thread_main(void*)
#3    Object "/snap/anbox/213/usr/bin/anbox", at 0x56411cf27358, in RenderThread::main()
#2    Object "/snap/anbox/213/usr/bin/anbox", at 0x56411d016060, in renderControl_decoder_context_t::decode(void*, unsigned long, IOStream*)
#1    Object "/snap/anbox/213/usr/bin/anbox", at 0x56411cf95562, in 
#0    Object "/snap/anbox/213/usr/bin/anbox", at 0x56411cf98429, in RendererConfigList::getPackInfo(int*, int*) const
Segmentation fault (Address not mapped to object [(nil)])
Segmentation fault (core image recorded)
```

Instead of recorded it might be dumped as I saw somewhere else

### ANBOX SESSION-MANAGER LOG IN PORTUGUESE:

```
caua@caua-HP-Stream-Laptop-11-y0XX:~$ anbox session-manager
[ 2021-12-13 17:33:09] [Renderer.cpp:128@initialize] Failed to select EGL configuration
Stack trace (most recent call last) in thread 2582:
#7    Object "[0xffffffffffffffff]", at 0xffffffffffffffff, in 
#6    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0x7f2f519c5292, in clone
#5    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", at 0x7f2f51d36608, in 
#4    Object "/snap/anbox/213/usr/bin/anbox", at 0x56411d01b314, in emugl::Thread::thread_main(void*)
#3    Object "/snap/anbox/213/usr/bin/anbox", at 0x56411cf27358, in RenderThread::main()
#2    Object "/snap/anbox/213/usr/bin/anbox", at 0x56411d016060, in renderControl_decoder_context_t::decode(void*, unsigned long, IOStream*)
#1    Object "/snap/anbox/213/usr/bin/anbox", at 0x56411cf95562, in 
#0    Object "/snap/anbox/213/usr/bin/anbox", at 0x56411cf98429, in RendererConfigList::getPackInfo(int*, int*) const
Segmentation fault (Address not mapped to object [(nil)])
Falha de segmentação (imagem do núcleo gravada)
```